# How to scroll to top after route hash has changed?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6.2

I have multiple pages in my Ext js app. Each page loads content through ajax requests. First page has list of items (links). When I scroll to bottom of the page and click on last item it redirects me to second page. On the second page content has loaded and page jumps (scroll) to position where I clicked link item (to the bottom of page).

I've tried `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` and `window.scroll(0, 0);` on click on link item and on `init` method in second page but it didn't work (it works for first page but when I go to second page it ignores position and moved to bottom of page).

The only way I can handle this is to use `setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), 1000)`, but it shows me old position for few miliseconds and then moves to top

I want my route pages load from top, not from position in previous page

Comment: Please add a minimal, working example code where we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?